# SVG `<path>` Imprecision

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry, precision

I use D3.js to draw hundreds of SVG `<path>`s on a canvas according to some calculations.

---

Here's a snippet from a typical SVG:

`<path element="true" class="generation1" d="M 0 0 H 11.276566666666668 V 10.733333333333333 H 0 L 0 0" transform="translate(90.21253333333334,0)" fill="rgb(153, 126, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(153, 126, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"></path><path element="true" class="generation1" d="M 0 0 H 11.276566666666668 V 10.733333333333333 H 0 L 0 0" transform="translate(112.76566666666668,0)" fill="rgb(153, 126, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(153, 126, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"></path><path element="true" class="generation1" d="M 11.276566666666668 10.733333333333333 L 11.276566666666668 5.366666666666666 L 0 5.366666666666666 L 0 10.733333333333333 Z" transform="translate(157.87193333333335,0)" fill="rgb(153, 126, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(153, 126, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"></path><path element="true" class="generation1" d="M 11.276566666666668 10.733333333333333 h -11.276566666666668 L 11.276566666666668 0 Z" transform="translate(180.42506666666668,0)" fill="rgb(153, 126, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(153, 126, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"></path>`

---

When I don't give each `<path>` a stroke of the same color, there are many, many tiny gaps between the shapes. When I add a stroke, however, other imperfections arise, à la below.

[image]

There are corners that don't meet, shapes that start in the wrong place and end up covered by others, gaps where the background shows or the wrong shape is visible, etc. The discrepancies are worse at certain zoom levels.

---

I seem to be having a version of the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172622/svg-gaps-when-using-rotate-transform), where the answerer said the problem lay with anti-aliasing. The answerer suggested adding `shape-rendering: crispEdges`, but this actually makes the problem far worse for me and did not satisfy the asker of that question. Adding a stroke eliminates most, but not all, of the gaps between `<path>`s, but again, that causes other problems.

I've also tried `shape-rendering: geometricPrecision`, but that didn't help.

---

What can I do to eliminate the gaps between shapes without creating additional discrepancies?

Comment: a) disable antialiasing which you don't like b) get over it or c) buy a much more expensive graphics card that does much higher resolution so you notice it less.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is for picky users, not just me, so I don't think b) or c) is an option. How can I disable antialising?

Comment: you already know that: shape-rendering: crispEdges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well it doesn't seem there's like really a great solution here.

I realized, though, that `stroke-width` can have values less than 1. So I played around with different fractions until most of the gaps between shapes were covered but other distortions were kept to a minimum.

I landed on `stroke-width: .5`.

If someone finds something else, I'll gladly accept it.